# /dev/vda1 is huge, can't understand why (output screenshots

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk-usage

When I run `df -h`, I get this:

[image: du -shx /* | sort -rh]

The `/dev/vda1` directory has 24G used. I'm trying to figure out which files take up the space. I tried `du -shx /* | sort -rh` and got this:

[image: )]

It lists `/usr` as the biggest with 2.8G inside. However it's 24G that are used, not 2.8G.

Using `ncdu` from inside `/dev` didn't help either:

[image]

What can I do to determine what takes up the 24G?

**EDIT**:

```
/# sudo ls -l /
total 108
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov  7 06:24 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 14 06:43 boot
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Nov 14 01:23 Bots
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  3580 Nov 15 00:10 dev
drwxr-xr-x 125 root root  4096 Dec  6 22:15 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jun 28 16:30 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Nov 14 06:43 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-169-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Nov 14 06:43 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-168-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4096 Jun 28 15:09 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 14 18:31 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Oct  4  2018 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  4  2018 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  4  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Sep 24 18:55 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 126 root root     0 Nov 15 00:10 proc
drwx------  25 root root  4096 Dec  6 20:39 root
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root   940 Dec  6 22:25 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Oct  1 06:34 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 20  2018 snap
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Nov 14 18:28 sources
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  4  2018 srv
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov 14 17:45 stuff
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Dec  6 22:30 sys
drwxrwxrwt  10 root root 12288 Dec  6 22:35 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Oct  4  2018 usr
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Oct  4  2018 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Nov 14 06:43 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-169-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Nov 14 06:43 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-168-generic
```

**EDIT**:
`ncdu /` gives this output:

```
--- / ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2.4 GiB [##########] /usr
  888.3 MiB [###       ] /var
  847.5 MiB [###       ] /stuff
  823.6 MiB [###       ] /root
  548.1 MiB [##        ] /lib
  293.5 MiB [#         ] /Bots
  267.4 MiB [#         ] /opt
  246.4 MiB [#         ] /boot
   15.6 MiB [          ] /bin
   13.3 MiB [          ] /sbin
   10.6 MiB [          ] /run
    8.0 MiB [          ] /etc
  180.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
   20.0 KiB [          ] /home
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0 KiB [          ] /snap
    4.0 KiB [          ] /dev
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /sources
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /media
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz


 Total disk usage:   6.2 GiB  Apparent size:   6.2 GiB  Items: 404555
```

**EDIT**:

```
# du -hsc .[!.]* *
du: cannot access '.[!.]*': No such file or directory
16M     bin
247M    boot
294M    Bots
4.0K    dev
8.1M    etc
20K     home
0       initrd.img
0       initrd.img.old
549M    lib
4.0K    lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
268M    opt
du: cannot access 'proc/25571/task/25571/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/25571/task/25571/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/25571/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/25571/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       proc
824M    root
11M     run
14M     sbin
8.0K    snap
4.0K    sources
4.0K    srv
848M    stuff
0       sys
180K    tmp
2.4G    usr
889M    var
0       vmlinuz
0       vmlinuz.old
6.3G    total
```

**EDIT**:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda     253:0    0   25G  0 disk
├─vda1  253:1    0 24.9G  0 part /
├─vda14 253:14   0    4M  0 part
└─vda15 253:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Comment: Probably in the root folder. Do `sudo ls -l /` and see if there is anything unusual. Having loads of Java error logs lying around doesn't help either, of course.

Comment: @Jos Could you please see my edit? I tried to run the command, but there doesn't seem to be anything suspicious.

Comment: Can you run `ncdu /` and post the results? Are you running any software that creates snapshots, like **Timeshift**? Also, please do not post pictures of text; it's much easier to read if you post everything like your *sudo ls -l /* output.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Please, see edit! It says that total used is 6.2G, while it should be around 24G...

Comment: Its possible that there are open file handles. Doing something like this: `sudo lsof |grep -i delete` . On my system right now there are 10037 files that are being held open but marked for deletion. This can eat some significant space

Comment: @stratus I run this command and some files indeed have been deleted, but then `df -h` again shows 24G as used in `dev/vda1`

Comment: the command shows you stuff that is *marked* for deletion but has not been deleted yet. The third last column has the file size in bytes. If you see something crazy big, the computer will eventually flush these files or you can reboot to get rid of them.

Comment: its also possible you have hidden files. These would not be counted with df commands. You can try this `du -hsc .[!.]* *`

Comment: @stratus Checked it (see edit), doesn't seem to have found anything...

Comment: can you do `lsblk`? The other option is that something is mounted on top of a directory. You can also try `mount -o bind / /mnt` this will mount all of root into /mnt. Then you can run the `du` command in /mnt

Comment: @stratus Done `lsblk`, see edit. Have run `mount -o bind / /mnt`, it didn't create any copies, did it? `ls /mnt` and `du` listed a lot of files, it's really hard to make sense of. Too big a list to copy in here.

Comment: the bind mount simply remounts only standard directories (i.e. it doesn't mount proc, sys, dev and so on). This also helps expose things that may be underneath. Although it doesn't look like you have this problem

Comment: @stratus I also found that `cd /` `ncdu` and while it scans, there appears a message `Warning: error scanning /proc/27113/fdinfo/3                                                                                                                                         x
  x  some directory sizes may not be correct     `. Could that have something to do with the space problem?

Comment: And how do I referce the mount command? Right now I have two `/usr`: one outside and one inside `/mnt`, and both seem to take space

Comment: I tried to remove the `/mnt` and everything seems to be very bad now ; (

Comment: you dont remove things you unmount `umount -l /mnt`. A bind mount simply makes another reference to whatever you have mounted

Comment: @stratus How would I remove that reference though?I freaked out because ncdu showed the total size as increased x2 so I thought those were copies. Well now at least I no longer have the space problem

Comment: as I said above simply umount it. `umount -l /mnt`